# Checking for convergence when the main tests fail

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge?

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1 \times 3 \times \dots \times (2k-1)}{2 \times 4 \times \dots \times 2k} \frac{1}{(2k+2)} \right]$$

The issue I am having is that most of the main tests seem to fail for this one. Especially the ratio test, which seems to be most appropriate one to try first. I am also toying with the comparison test, but I am not sure what to compare it to.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think Raabe's test will work. The other way is to use Stirling's formula to get an asymptotic for the $k$-th term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), we have:
$$\dfrac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\sim \sqrt{\pi n}$$
Let $a_k=  \dfrac{1 \times 3 \times \dots \times (2k-1)}{2 \times 4 \times \dots \times 2k} \dfrac{1}{(2k+2)}$, we get:
$$a_n\sim_{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}(2n+1)}\sim \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n^3}}$$, it converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can  use that if $v_n=\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{2k})$, then there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $v_n\leq \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ (take the log, use $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $x>-1$, and the fact that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\log n+O(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The $k$th term $f(k)$ is equal to $(2k)!/[2^{2k}k!^2(2k+2)].$ From Stirling's Formula $\lim_{k\to \infty}(k/e)^k\sqrt {2\pi k}\;/k!=1$ we obtain $$f(k)=\frac {1}{2k+2}O(1/\sqrt k)=O(1/k^{3/2})$$ as $k\to \infty.$ By comparison to $\sum_k k^{-3/2},$ which converges by the Cauchy condensation test, we see that $\sum_kf(k)$ converges.